# Putting code in first frame. Same as timelinecoding?

Tags: actionscript-3

Hitting u guys with a noob question. Trying to make sense of things regarding AS3 code and where to put it. As of now I´ve been putting it on first (AND ONLY) frame in my swf's. Mixing this with use of some extended classes. Is this considered as timeline coding or is timeline coding when using the timeline and multiple frames for different kinds of code? Hope this isn´t a duplicate but I did some research and couldn´t find any specific info regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I would not consider it as timeline coding.

But, I would put that code in the main document class (as an external .as file).

In the Properties panel, when the stage is selected, you see a **Class** field:

[image: Document class]

You can assign a class to your stage, Flash will search for a file named as the class on compile-time.

Here is a tutorial:

http://active.tutsplus.com/tutorials/actionscript/quick-tip-how-to-use-a-document-class-in-flash/

Benefits will include more clarity of code, and long-time maintenance ease.

Comment: As an include? Read some threads about that but didn´t really grasp the benefit? Would you mind shortly sell this to me?

Comment: @user2239256 You're welcome. Trust me, once you start using the document class you will never go back!